# Checking if String contains another whole String

Tags: java, regex, string

So, I've been trying to find online if there's a way to have a String be search for another whole string in java. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that works.

What I mean is this:

```
String str = "this is a test";
```

If I search for `this is` it should return `true`. But if I search for `this i` it should be false.

I've tried using `String.matches()`, but that won't work because some of the strings being search may have a [, ], ?, etc in it - which would throw it off. Using `String.indexOf(search) != -1` won't work either because it would return true for partial words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also separate words from non alphabetic character and not only whitespaces you can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms. Try maybe this way

```
String str = "[this] is...";
String search = "[this] is";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?!<\\p{IsAlphabetic})"
        + Pattern.quote(search) + "(?!\\p{IsAlphabetic})");
boolean matches = p.matcher(str).find();
```

It will check if matched part has no alphabetic characters before or after it.

Note: `\\p{IsAlphabetic}` includes all Unicode alphabetic characters like `ż` `ź` `ć`, not only `a-z` `A-Z` range.

Comment: Works exactly the way I need it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `\b`, the zero-width word boundary delimiter, in a regex.

```
String str = "this is a test";
String search = "this is";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("\\b%s\\b", Pattern.quote(search)));
boolean matches = p.matcher(Pattern.quote(str)).find();
```

Comment: That won't work. Using `String.matches(".*?\\b" + search + "\\b*.?");` wouldn't pickup something like "[test]".

Comment: Sure it will. You just need to use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) first.

Comment: Doing this still returns false now.

Comment: Ah yes - should have used `Matcher#find()` instead of `#matches()`.

Comment: When searching a String like `String str = "[this] is...";` It will return false when I search `[this] is`

Comment: Got it - What I had to do was do `p.matcher(Pattern.quote(str)).find();` to have it properly find the symbols in it.

Comment: My mistake - I didn't think that'd actually be necessary.

Comment: Well now if I had a String `[this] is a test` and I searched `[this]` it would return false again.